# List of Emails to Student Activities Board of all Universities

Tags: data-request, data.gov

Does anyone know if there is a public list of all the emails of the student activities board (or something similar to that- student affairs, student governing boards, etc) of all universities?

Comment: The subject of your question and the text of your question don't agree. Do you want emails *to* or just the email addresses? Please edit either the subject or the text.

Comment: You *might* be able to get outgoing broadcast e-mail from a FOIA-type request to a public university.  It's doubtful that incoming or individual communications would be available -- there's likely to be student information in the e-mails (if nothing else, linking students to specific organizations) and that could get universities in the U.S. in trouble under FERPA if it were released.